# Pure, residual, 2-dimensional, semisimple $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ representations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, elliptic-curves, langlands-conjectures, modular-representation-theory

Let $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ be the absolute Galois group of the rationals. I want to know how many isomorphism classes of 2-dimensional, irreducible, pure Galois representations are there over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, that are unramified outside a fixed finite set of primes $S$.

Is there any literature on the classification of such representations? For example, are there finitely many? Do they all come from residual representations associated to Galois representations of modular forms of a given weight/conductor?

I am particularly interested in understanding the isomorphism classes of the semisimplifications of the residual representations associated to Tate modules of Elliptic curves with nice integral models.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://www.math.titech.ac.jp/~taguchi/bib/jami.pdf .